# Sorted para fórmula de Bhaskara

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um exercício para resolver e estou com um problema, ele não é para ser feito em lista ou dicionário.
Caso tenha 2 raízes reais elas devem ser impressas em ordem crescente, o problema é que deve ser impresso em um print o seguinte "**as raízes da equação são X e Y**". Não estou conseguindo montar o print com ambos os resultados em ordem crescente.

Fiz o código a seguir:

```
import math

a = float(input("Digite o valor de a: "))

b = float(input("Digite o valor de b: "))

c = float(input("Digite o valor de c: "))

delta = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

if delta == 0:
    raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a)
    print(f"a raiz desta equação é {raiz1}")
else:
    if delta < 0:
        print("esta equação não possui raízes reais")
    else:
        raiz1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a)
        raiz2 = (-b - math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a)
        result = raiz1, raiz2
        print("As raízes da equação são", sorted(result))
```

**EDIT:**
*Resolvido sem o uso do sort*

Fiz duas verificações e consegui resolver desta maneira:

```
if raiz1 < raiz2:
    print(f"as raízes da equação são {raiz1} e {raiz2}")
elif raiz2 < raiz1:
    print(f"as raízes da equação são {raiz2} e {raiz1}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa colocar o elif se você não tem mais condições para considerar.

```
if raiz1 < raiz2:
    print(f'as raízes da equação são {raiz1} e {raiz2}')
else:
    print(f'as raízes da equação são {raiz2} e {raiz1}')
```